# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Shutdown in progress during unit test

Tags: java, android-studio, robolectric

Recently, some tests of mine have started flakily failing with the following exception:

```
[Robolectric] tests.integration.TourQueryHandlerTest.testLinkedEmployeeAccompanyingNurse: sdk=25; resources=legacy
[Robolectric] NOTICE: legacy resources mode is deprecated; see http://robolectric.org/migrating/#migrating-to-40

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Shutdown in progress

    at java.lang.ApplicationShutdownHooks.add(ApplicationShutdownHooks.java:66)
    at java.lang.Runtime.addShutdownHook(Runtime.java:211)
    at org.robolectric.util.TempDirectory.<init>(TempDirectory.java:23)
    at org.robolectric.android.internal.ParallelUniverse.setUpApplicationState(ParallelUniverse.java:90)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.beforeTest(RobolectricTestRunner.java:377)
    at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner$2.evaluate(SandboxTestRunner.java:252)
    at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner.runChild(SandboxTestRunner.java:130)
    at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner.runChild(SandboxTestRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner$1.evaluate(SandboxTestRunner.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

At the time of writing, it appears to only happen to robolectric tests, but not to all of them, and certainly not all of them at the same time.

I've tried to look into it using our best friend Google, but as of yet I haven't found any results specific to Android studio or robolectric

I've found this one:
https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/308650/why-is-the-jvm-failing-to-start-with-javalangilleg/
where it appears to have something to do with adding a shutdown hook on a process that already calles System.exit();

I'm looking into it, but it would be strange that sometimes the tests pass, and sometimes they don't.